# Filter "ONLY" in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, filter, data-manipulation

#Dummy df

```
Store <- c("S1", "S2", "S2","S3")
Product <- c("Paper", "Pen", "Paper","Pen")

df <- data.frame(Store, Product)
```

In this example, I want to "only" extract "S3" store when filtering "Pen". By normal filter function it brings back both S2 and S3.
The idea is to get back the Store which only sells Pen not other things.

```
df %>% filter(Product == "Pen")
```

This gives back both S2 & S3

P.S: Consider that the data set is much larger, so I can't put a specific filter on the Store column.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Sia, welcome to SO! it looks like you want to filter on 2 conditions, like `df %>% filter(Product == "Pen" & Store =="S3")`. Does that get you where you want to be?

Comment: Hi Michael, sorry my post was not so clear! I'm familiar with conditional filter, however, in this case, data set is very big with so many other Stores & Products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best solution is to use `group_by()` before `filter()`. This will allow you to check that *all* the products for a given store are "Pen" as follows:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Store) %>%
  filter(all(Product == "Pen")) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>   Store Product
#>   <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 S3    Pen
```

Answer (score 1):

```
subset(df, Store == "S3" & Product == "Pen")
```

Note that you can compare execution times for `subset` vs. `dplyr` using the `Sys.time` function:

```
start <- Sys.time()
# execution code here
stop <- Sys.time()
duration <- stop - start
```

Also see the `data.table` package for managing large data sets in R:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Comment: Consider a much larger data set. With thousand Stores and Products, any idea for that situation?

Comment: Don’t think this is quite what’s being asked for. The requirement is to filter for stores which *only* have "Pen" in `Product`. This solution just gives rows where `Store == "S3"` and `Product == "Pen"`, no?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the prettiest solution, but it should work:

```
df <- df[df$Product == "S3" & df$Store == "Pen", ]
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that this will not work well when there are missings in the `Product` or `Store` columns. A safer solution would be to use `subset` as suggested by SteveM.

Answer (score 0):

the dplyr package is very useful for these kinds of operations.

The `filter()` and `select()` functions are data wrangling workhorses.

You can use multiple conditions as arguments to the `filter()` function.

```
library(dplyr)

df%>%filter(Store=='S3', Product=='Pen')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to get a list of "single item stores" - those, that sell only a single item.

And for those that do check whether the (single) item they sell equals "Pen"

```
library(dplyr)

Store <- c("S1", "S2", "S2","S3")
Product <- c("Paper", "Pen", "Paper","Pen")

df <- data.frame(Store, Product)

single_item_stores <- df %>% 
  group_by(Store) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  filter(n == 1) %>% 
  pull(Store)

df %>% 
  filter(Store %in% single_item_stores & Product == "Pen")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want this-

- First expr inside `[]` selects only those stores which select only one item.
- second expr select stores which sells `Pen` at least.
- so combining both may give you your desired result

```r
Store <- c("S1", "S2", "S2","S3")
Product <- c("Paper", "Pen", "Paper","Pen")

df <- data.frame(Store, Product)

df$Store[as.numeric(ave(df$Product, df$Store, FUN = function(x) length(x))) == 1 & df$Product == 'Pen']
#> [1] "S3"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

For a more complex case, when you may have duplicate hrows

```r
Store <- c("S1", "S2", "S2","S3", "S3")
Product <- c("Paper", "Pen", "Paper","Pen", "Pen")

df <- data.frame(Store, Product)

unique(df$Store[as.numeric(ave(df$Product, df$Store, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))) == 1 & df$Product == 'Pen'])
#> [1] "S3"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>